# Create Package from folder structure with subpackages

Tags: julia

I have been given a folder called `PackageName` with the following structure.

```
PackageName/
    |- SubPackage.jl/
           |- src/
                  |- MyModule.jl
           |- test/
                  |- runtests.jl
           |- Project.toml
           |- Manifest.toml
    |- Project.toml
    |- Manifest.toml
    |- .gitignore
    |- .gitattributes
    |- README.md
```

Inside `PackageName` there are various `.git` files like `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` and `README.md`. There are also a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml` which are required in a Julia package. Finally, there are various folders with the structure of `SubPackage`. Essentially they also contain a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml`. They also contain a `src/` directory with a Module named `MyModule.jl` and a `test/` directory with some unit testing. The `MyModule.jl` has a function called `myfunction()`, which is exported.

I would like to use all the `SubPackage`-style packages but I am encountering some issues. `PackageName` doesn't seem to be a proper Julia package because

- it doesn't have a `src/` directory.
- it's `Project.toml` has an `author`, a `version` and `[deps]` fields but lacks a `name` and `uuid`.

What is the best way to go about using the packages in this folder properly within a Julia environment? Essentially I would like to be able to do `using PackageName` and being able to use `myfunction()`.

Comment: Why do you need `PackageName` to be a "proper Julia package"? It doesn't seem to have any source code according to your setup (no `src`).

Comment: @fredrikekre I am open to other possibilities that work!
Basically I have quite a few subpackages in this folder, say `SubPackage1`, `SubPackage2`, all the way until `SubPackage10`. Each one of them has got various functions in them and `uses` many registered packages. I need to do some analyses which involve using all of these `SubPackages` (and modifying them) so I would like the dependencies etc to all work out. I would like to be able to `add` a package to the environment and this to work seemlessly

Comment: @fredrikekre the key problem is that if I `cd` into the `PackageName` folder using the julia REPL and then do `] add SubPackage1` then I get the error `ERROR: Did not find a git repository at 'SubPackage1.jl'` because none of them is a git repository

Comment: Use `dev` for tracking local paths instead of `add`.